# I updated my Mac (to Monterey 12.5) and now none of my apps that I installed from the internet are launching

Tags: macos, crash, monterey

I recently updated my Mac to Monterey 12.5 and now none of the apps I have are updating. Here's a crash report from when I tried to open OBS. I attempted to reinstall, but no luck. Is there anything that I can do to fix this bar reinstalling my OS?

Translated Report (Full Report Below)

```
Incident Identifier: 9CB24C14-F75D-4B61-94DC-A0B500896C91
CrashReporter Key:   DF1992D6-F0D3-CE72-DB5F-6E97229369E7
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             obs [952]
Path:                /Applications/OBS.app/Contents/MacOS/obs
Identifier:          com.obsproject.obs-studio
Version:             27.2.2 (27.2.2)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Background
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.obsproject.obs-studio [1065]

Date/Time:           2023-04-30 20:58:29.1230 -0500
Launch Time:         2023-04-30 20:58:28.9829 -0500
OS Version:          macOS 12.5 (21G72)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00007ff7fff849b0
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [952]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   runtime                             0x7ff7fff849b0 0x7ff7fff67000 + 121264
1   runtime                             0x7ff7fff84394 0x7ff7fff67000 + 119700
2   runtime                             0x7ff7fff7c0c4 0x7ff7fff67000 + 86212
3   runtime                             0x7ff7fff6aae0 0x7ff7fff67000 + 15072
4   ???                                            0x3 ???


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000003   x2: 0x000000000000003c   x3: 0x000000000000002c
    x4: 0x0000000000000303   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000003e0
    x8: 0x00007ff7fffa2000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00007ff7fffa28f4
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000039  x14: 0x00007ff7fffa27a8  x15: 0x00007ff7fff8a818
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0x00007ff7fff936e1  x18: 0x000000030482404b  x19: 0x00007ff7fff982e1
   x20: 0x00007ff7fff92ba2  x21: 0x0000000000000063  x22: 0x00007ff7fff92b96  x23: 0x0000000304822fb0
   x24: 0x00000001084fe2e0  x25: 0x0000000000000248  x26: 0x0000000000000009  x27: 0x00000002007c91b8
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x0000000304822f70   lr: 0x00007ff7fff849a8
    sp: 0x0000000304822f50   pc: 0x00007ff7fff849b0 cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x000000010eb64000  esr: 0xf2000001 (Breakpoint) brk 1

Binary Images:
    0x7ff7fff67000 -     0x7ff7fff96fff runtime (*) <ef33add1-6b70-3cc9-8bbc-c8544b609d2b> /usr/libexec/rosetta/runtime
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF
```

---

### Full Report

```
{"app_name":"obs","timestamp":"2023-04-30 20:58:29.00 -0500","app_version":"27.2.2","slice_uuid":"de6ddd60-cf0c-388e-bfbf-5853f0cf5c67","build_version":"27.2.2","platform":0,"bundleID":"com.obsproject.obs-studio","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.5 (21G72)","incident_id":"9CB24C14-F75D-4B61-94DC-A0B500896C91","name":"obs"}
{
  "uptime" : 250,
  "procLaunch" : "2023-04-30 20:58:28.9829 -0500",
  "procRole" : "Background",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookAir10,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 6200736673,
  "coalitionID" : 1065,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.5",
    "build" : "21G72",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2023-04-30 20:58:29.1230 -0500",
  "incident" : "9CB24C14-F75D-4B61-94DC-A0B500896C91",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 952,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 6204088795,
  "translated" : true,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "obs",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/OBS.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/obs",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"27.2.2","CFBundleVersion":"27.2.2","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.obsproject.obs-studio"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"537A020F-E3A6-5ED6-A10D-92DCF2FE9E1E","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.obsproject.obs-studio",
  "crashReporterKey" : "DF1992D6-F0D3-CE72-DB5F-6E97229369E7",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x00007ff7fff849b0","rawCodes":[1,140703128111536],"type":"EXC_BREAKPOINT","signal":"SIGTRAP"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":5,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Trace\/BPT trap: 5","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":952},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":10261,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":3},{"value":60},{"value":44},{"value":771},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":992},{"value":140703128231936},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":140703128234228,"symbolLocation":140,"symbol":"__crashreporter_info__"},{"value":0},{"value":57},{"value":140703128233896},{"value":140703128135704},{"value":18446744073709551585},{"value":140703128172257},{"value":12960546891},{"value":140703128191713},{"value":140703128169378},{"value":99},{"value":140703128169366},{"value":12960542640},{"value":4434420448},{"value":584},{"value":9},{"value":8598098360,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"dyld_all_image_infos"},{"value":1}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":140703128111528},"cpsr":{"value":1610616832},"fp":{"value":12960542576},"sp":{"value":12960542544},"esr":{"value":4060086273,"description":"(Breakpoint) brk 1"},"pc":{"value":140703128111536,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":4541792256}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":121264,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":119700,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":86212,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":15072,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":3,"imageIndex":1}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 140703127990272,
    "size" : 196608,
    "uuid" : "ef33add1-6b70-3cc9-8bbc-c8544b609d2b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/libexec\/rosetta\/runtime",
    "name" : "runtime"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=840K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=840K(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=136.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=136.1M(100%)\n\n                                   VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                           SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                        =======  ======= \nRosetta Generic                         8K        2 \nRosetta IndirectBranch (reserved)      32K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nRosetta JIT                         128.0M        1 \nSTACK GUARD                          56.0M        1 \nStack                                8176K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE (reserved)                 24K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\n__DATA                                 80K        3 \n__DATA_CONST                           80K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                            240K        4 \n__TEXT                                624K        2 \nmapped file                          5272K        7 \n===========                        =======  ======= \nTOTAL                               198.2M       25 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space      198.1M       25 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60186475825c62000ccf5450",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000026
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "60f8ddccefea4203d95cbeef",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000025
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "c28e4ee6-1b08-4f90-8e05-2809e78310a3",
      "experimentId" : "6317d2003d24842ff850182a",
      "deploymentId" : 400000012
    }
  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}

Model: MacBookAir10,1, BootROM 7459.141.1, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1, Apple M1, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: Wi-Fi, wl0: Mar 23 2022 19:57:59 version 18.60.27.0.7.8.129 FWID 01-570be953
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
```

Comment: You upgraded to Monterey from what?  Why not go to Ventura?  Were you using OBS via Rosetta?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I'm just stupid. After digging around for what "EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)" meant I tried running the app in terminal and realized I needed to reinstall Rosetta